Converting SQL to LINQ with Min and Max functions
I have the following SQL snippet that I am trying to convert to a LINQ query as part of a more complex query but I cannot see how to get started:
SELECT
    AT.PrimaryIDChanged AS PID,
    MAX(AT.ProcessID) AS EventTypeID,
    MIN(AT.AuditDateTime) AS EventDate
FROM
    dbo.AuditTrail AS AT    
WHERE
    AT.AuditTargetTableID = 13
    AND AT.ProcessID IN (30, 31)
GROUP BY
    AT.PrimaryIDChanged 

Target is EF6.
I have no code to share as yet

Check the Group By documentation

That's the problem, I cannot see how to start; I can do the Group By but not the max and min

The docs show how to call .Count() on a collection, and how to use MIN or MAX 4-5 lines below that. Did you try reading the docs? I emphasize reading vs looking for an exact answer

@PeterSmith, just because you can doesn't mean you should; you will create a lock on the table and get the whole dataset in memory. if you can do it in SQL then do it in SQL

@WalterVerhoeven that's completely wrong. The LINQ query will get translated to the same SQL query shown above and executed as SQL on the server

@PanagiotisKanavos a linq query is a linq statement ist.

@WalterVerhoeven there's no difference, just different syntax: query vs fluent. Are you confusing EF Core 1's client-side evaluation with the fluent API? Why don't you actually try this and inspect what's sent to the database? SQL Server has a lot of ways to monitor SQL: Activity Monitor, Extended Events, the legacy SQL Server profiler. You'll see the same queries are generated no matter what

You can do it in Query Syntax like this:
var data =
    from at in context.AuditTrail
    where at.AuditTargetTableID == 13
       && new[]{ 30, 13 }.Contains(at.ProcessID)
    group at by at.PrimaryIDChanged into g
    select new {
        PID = g.Key,
        EventTypeID = g.Max(at => at.ProcessID),
        EventDate = g.Min(at => at.AuditDateTime),
    };

Note the into g, this allows you to do multiple aggregation functions on the whole group.

This is done in EF to create SQL and not Linq, this is safe to do :-)

EF is a LINQ provider, in other words LINQ is the syntax (and functions such as .Where and .Select) and EF is the query provider which actually runs the query. They are orthogonal to each other.

Roughly:
var processIDs = new[] { 30, 31 };

var results =
   context
   .AuditTrail
   .Where(at => at.AuditTargetTableID == 13)
   .Where(at => processIDs.Contains(at.ProcessID))
   .GroupBy(at => at.PrimaryIDChanged)
   .Select(g => new {
      PID = g.Key,
      EventTypeID = g.Max(at => at.ProcessID),
      EventDate = g.Min(at => at.AuditDateTime)
   });

GroupBy gives you an IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> where an IGrouping is an IEnumerable<TSource> but also has a Key property of type TKey. So in other words you get an enumerable of enumerables, each inner enumerable having a key. You can then project each of these groups into something else.
Note I have not tested this code against an actual model since I don't have one atm.

@Charlieface yeah, you're right the group cannot be empty, just a reflex on my part to avoid exception.

I would have liked to accept both but sadly can't
